# how to integrate pre approved chained adaptive payment

Tags: php, ios, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

i want to integrate payment gateway in which payment will be debited from some one else account to account of user using application

suppose

owner of application is A and two users B and c using the application

when user B uses application then amount transferred from his account to admin that is user A and that is possible because user B uses application and amount transferred from his account

but when C will use application the amount will be transferred from admin's account to his account

i researched about it and get there is a process of pre approvals  in pay pal but i dint get any detailed explanation about it

please help if anybody knows about it do we need any support from web services in this or can i handle it on application end

and i also got to know that their is a chained adaptive procedure in paypal

can i integrate both chained and pre approved payments together

such that when user B uses application amount transferred from his account and when user b uses application after deduction some amount rest amount transferred to user B

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set up preapprovals and then subsequently run chained payments from said preapproval. More information on Adaptive Payments, to include both Chained and Preapprovals, can be found [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-accounts/integration-guide/ACIntroduction/). As for a mobile integration, the only native solution would be our legacy MPL product which can be found [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MPL/). However, please keep in mind that MPL is being deprecated so support and maintenance/updates/fixes are limited.

Comment: can u give me any example

Comment: Various code samples can be found with the links in the answer or https://github.com/paypal?query=codesamples as well.  Essentially you will create the preapproval and get your preapproval key in your success response.  You can run payments off of that once you have that key.  Subsequently, when you do the Pay API to run the Chained Payment, you'll also pass in the preapproval key to let PayPal know to take the funds from the previously created preapproval agreement.